# Change material texture unity in editor don't apply

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a question. I am trying to change other material to a model 3D. But it don't show texture content instead of it is just a simple color[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlZM5.png)

Comment: Did you add material to object

Answer (score 0):

Either you didn't add the material to the object, or the UV mapping of the object is wrong